# RSA factorization, explanation of the c^d % n

Tags: algorithm, rsa, modulo

In my RSA, I am using the following code for computing c^d % m. 
However, I am not sure, how this version containing the double mod operation, works in the background.

```
function [f] = rsa ( m, d, c )    
f = 1;
for index = 1:d
        f = f *  mod(c , m );
        f = mod( f, m);
end
```

There is another method using a binary exppansion of the exponent d, where the exponent is represented by the sum of 2^n, which is known for me.

Could somebody help me? Thanks.

Comment: `(a * b) % m` is equal to `((a % m) * (b % m)) % m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ignore the mod function calls for the moment, each iteration of the loop will simply multiply f (starting at 1) by c.

Therefore, after d iterations, f will equal

1*c*c*...*c = c^d

You could then apply the modulus operation at the end to compute "c^d%m".

However, doing it like this is very likely to overflow, so the code instead computes the modulus during every iteration to prevent overflow.

In summary, this code is simply doing a bruteforce calculation of "c^d%m".  This approach will be far too slow in practice as d tends to be a very large number in RSA.